# JazzyViewPager + ImageLoading = OutOfMemory

Tags: android, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

I'm getting OutOfMemory error when I scroll through 70 or so images using JazzyViewPager.

There seems to be a bad memory leak somewhere in the Jazzy pager. I see it's holding on to the images even when i scroll way past them. Even on beefier devices I'm getting out of memory after scrolling through 70 images or so.

I'm using the universal-image-loader with this view pager, so not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a leak in JazzyViewPager.

I ran a memory profiler and found that JazzyViewPager maintains a map of all the added views:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Object> mObjs = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Object>();

public void setObjectForPosition(Object obj, int position) {
    mObjs.put(Integer.valueOf(position), obj);
}
```

It always adds objects, but never removes.

To fix this, I added a remove method to the JazzyViewPager:

```
public void removeObject(int position) {
    Object removed = mObjs.remove(position);
    if (removed != null) {
        LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "Removed obj at pos " + position);
    }
}
```

and called it from my adapter's `destroyItem()`:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object obj) {
    container.removeView(((JazzyViewPager)container).findViewFromObject(position));

    // make sure to remove the reference from the jazzyviewpager map
    ((JazzyViewPager)container).removeObject(position);
}
```

I monitored the memory usage and everything's fine now.